# Vega-lite: How do you customize legend labels?

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, vega-lite

I have this bar chart that's made with [Vega-lite](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/) (code and pic below).

But I want to customize the legend labels so that instead of ***videoGame*** it's ***Video Game*** and instead of ***tv*** its ***TV***. Is there anyway to do this?

[image]

```
lineChart = vegalite ({
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
   "width": 560,
   "height": 200,
   "data": {"values": chartData},
   "mark": {"type": "bar"},
   "encoding": {
     "x": {"field": "year_reference", "type": "temporal", "axis": {"title": "Year", "grid": true}},
     "y": {"field": "reference_count_total", "type": "quantitative", "axis": {"title": "References", "grid": true}},
   "color": {
     "field": "title_type", 
     "scale": {
       "domain": [
         "tv",
         "movie",
         "video",
         "videoGame"
       ],
       "range": [
         "#9e9ac8",
         "#74c476",
         "#a6761d",
         "#6baed6"
       ]
     },
     "legend": true,
     "title": "Reference Type"
    },
 }
```

})

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just provide `labelExpr` in legend, where you can conditionally give the labels depending on your fields data.
Refer the below code or the chart in [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemjEA2AAxL4NMljQAmXfpBqkmFKlDEkghnAhoA2qEx1BcAPqYAJ44cGggmMSKIIFwSABOfnFwAGZwSbJQoegAjLr82ab85gVRSanpmX5QbAyymAFstoJouQC+Cl4+-kEhYQhsxDShSjHxiSlpcBlZILn5hcWmpRMV-tW19ZiNTi267Z2YvgHBM4NqcGxRowllk9NhcwVFuiVKt6tVNXUNTbv74V1jr10GcLgBxJAIYbRWI3FZTTIPPJPRbLcoItZfTbbZqoNoAXXaIGQcQA1mgvCcwkx4iAiQi2GoaLIyBSQAAPNnJIaCNRha7jdH3JQ9GaYRA4NhxHZKJDsmhuewAw4zACasKiZDi6jQmDiLlaRMCXJ5fPQ7wxnw2Pxl4Sp6AAjgwkHU6DYaKQonKFWzvCqwgAleHTNxKLU61B6g1E6qCKUmuC8sJ+o6iqLQJxZUBqNjIZkecKRJT9QbQ0GXJTliFQkD4t4ushZdwgADEAE44G2kFAABxRFsAdgALFAhwPtP2kNpx9k+UoW9oaXA1BPCUpfI3ZGbQIIkExEwBRdk4OJhayYBgISi7-eCAAEAF4H3eAOQRF93gD8r4AKsQP6gd7npe157omj7Pi+JZDB+34vgAsgMMF3qgwFXje4FPq+5awa+ABq6gXAB+GEWwd7VnAL50iKXSBsGmR3j+VKGq0QA)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 560,
  "height": 200,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "title_type": "tv",
        "year_reference": "10-12-2012",
        "reference_count_total": 10
      },
      {
        "title_type": "movie",
        "year_reference": "10-12-2012",
        "reference_count_total": 10
      },
      {
        "title_type": "video",
        "year_reference": "10-12-2012",
        "reference_count_total": 10
      },
      {
        "title_type": "videoGame",
        "year_reference": "10-12-2012",
        "reference_count_total": 10
      }
    ]
  },
  "mark": {"type": "bar"},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "year_reference",
      "type": "temporal",
      "axis": {"title": "Year", "grid": true}
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "reference_count_total",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {"title": "References", "grid": true}
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "title_type",
      "scale": {
        "domain": ["tv", "movie", "video", "videoGame"],
        "range": ["#9e9ac8", "#74c476", "#a6761d", "#6baed6"]
      },
      "legend": {
        "labelExpr": "datum.label == 'tv' ? 'Tv' : datum.label == 'movie' ? 'Movie' :datum.label == 'video' ? 'Video' : 'Video Game'"
      },
      "title": "Reference Type"
    }
  }
}
```